# Alter source array with _.orderBy

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there any way to make `_.orderBy` alter the provided array? Using the example below it only seems to return a sorted result, leaving the provided array intact.

```
var arr = [{x: 1},{x: 2}];

console.log(_.orderBy(arr, 'x', 'desc')[0].x, arr[0].x);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w5hoeurs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Lodash documentation on [orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs#orderBy):

> Returns
>   (Array): Returns the new sorted array.

So, your code would be:

```
var arr = [{x: 1},{x: 2}];
arr = _.orderBy(arr,['x'],['desc']);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment